# trying to move a select generated from an array in my JS into a hidden form

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, select, display

I would like to insert/move the following Select created in JS and displayed in the body, into a hidden form like the one at the end.Thanks
for the help

```
const avenidas = ['Diego Armando Maradona','Argentina', 'Mexico 86', 'Dalma', 'Gianina','Segurola y Habana','Mano de Dios','La pelota no se mancha'];
    //DECLARE VARIABLE ,  FOREACH list options
    let innerSelectAve = '';
    avenidas.forEach((avenida, index) => innerSelectAve += ` < option value = '${index}' > $ {
        avenida
    } < /option>`)
    //add SELECT Y listen EVENT CHANGE
    $('body').prepend(`<select id="selectAvenida">${innerSelect}</select>`);
    document.getElementById('selectAvenida').onchange = (e) => {
        $('body').append(`<h4>SELECCIONADO ${avenidas[e.target.value]}</h4>`);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="FormController/save" method="POST" id="theForm" style="display: none">MY FORM </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line from:

```
$('body').prepend(`<select id="selectAvenida">${innerSelect}</select>`);
```

To:

```
$('body #theForm').prepend(`<select id="selectAvenida">${innerSelect}</select>`);
```

Also, you would be keeping it hidden, there is no need for the onchange event:

```
document.getElementById('selectAvenida').onchange = (e) => {
    $('body').append(`<h4>SELECCIONADO ${avenidas[e.target.value]}</h4>`);
}
```